# sleep() in infinite while loop not printing value if not ended with \n

Tags: c++, c

This code work's fine :

```
int main()
{
while(1){

printf("hi\n");
sleep(1);
}

return 0;
}
```

Output:
hi
hi
hi
...

but when we remove '\n' it will print nothing?

```
int main()
{
while(1){

printf("hi");
sleep(1);
}

return 0;
}
```

Output:
NO OUTPUT

Plz anyone give explaination of this behaviour :)

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stdout` if buffered by default, so to flush it you should out `\n` or fill that internal buffer completely. If such behavior is undesired - you can flush it manually with `fflush(stdout)` or turn off buffering with `setbuffer(stdout, NULL, 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're not seeing anything printed is because the output is buffered.

The reason you see prints when you suffix \n is that on some systems, a newline causes the buffer to flush. You can flush stdout manually like so:

```
int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        printf("hi");
        fflush(stdout);
        sleep(1);
    }
return 0;
}
```